# Measure time spent in a webpage and store it in the database

Tags: javascript, python, django

I have a **Django** project (prototype) running locally in my laptop. About 10 users will access locally this website (for testing purposes). I would like to measure how much time each user spent  on each page of my prototype and store this time in the database.

Can anybody suggest me any idea how to do this?
Thank you.

Comment: Use an analytics tool.

Comment: I'm not really sure if analytics tools work locally...